# Pycharm and R plugin - RConsole can't start

Tags: r, linux, plugins, pycharm

I installed the R plugin for PyCharm and everything seems fine except that the rconsole is giving this issue below:

RWrapper terminated, exitcode: 1

```
rpath: RPaths(home=/usr/lib64/R, share=/usr/share/R, include=/usr/include/R, doc=/usr/share/doc/R-3.6.0, path=/home/casxp/anaconda3/bin:/home/casxp/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/casxp/.local/bin:/home/casxp/bin, ldPath=/usr/lib64/R/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib)

stdout: 
stderr: /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux --with-timeout
/home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux)

/home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux)

/home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux)

/home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux)

/home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux)

/home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/casxp/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/plugins/rplugin/R-3.6/rwrapper-x64-linux)
```

I did check the libc version:

```
ldd --version

ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

Also, the libc is located in `/usr/lib64/libc.so.6`.
Is there a path I need to explicitly specify to get it to work? It seems like I need to set ldpath to include the `/usr/lib64` path but where do I set it?

Please let me know if someone knows how to get around that.